# How to resolve spawn EPERM issue in angular

Tags: angular, angular15

When run my angular 15 application i am getting below the error. I am not able to find out the solution for this. How to resole this issue. please help to find the solution.

I am using below the versions.
Node: v16.15.0
npm:8.5.5
RXJS: 7.8.1

ng serve -o

```
An unhandled exception occurred: spawn EPERM

See "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-8ihUnj\angular-errors.log" for further details.

C:\zon\latest\poc\node_modules\rxjs\internal\util\hostReportError.js:4

    setTimeout(function () { throw err; }, 0);

                             ^

Error: spawn EPERM

    at ChildProcess.spawn (node:internal/child_process:413:11)

    at Object.spawn (node:child_process:700:9)

    at baseOpen (C:\zon\latest\poc\node_modules\open\index.js:205:34)

    at async MergeMapSubscriber.project (C:\zon\latest\poc\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\builders\dev-server\index.js:234:21) {

  errno: -4048,

  code: 'EPERM',

  syscall: 'spawn'

}
```

Comment: Seems like a permission issue, do you have apt permissions to run the project ?

Comment: @Navitas28: Apt means?

Comment: Apologies for the miscommunication, `appropriate`.  It seems the folder `zon/latest/poc` don't have sufficient permission. You can also try by removing `.angular` folder and re run the app